# how to upload a file to attachment in salesforce using lightning?

Tags: lightning

This is the helper class in lightning:

```
({
    MAX_FILE_SIZE: 750 000,
    save: function(component) {
        var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        -- --some logic-- --
})
```

From component I am calling this save method but I am getting this error:

```
Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$fileUpload$controller$save [TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c$fileUpload$controller$save}.
```

Please try again.

Please help me.

Comment: In case  you were wondering, you can't do this: `MAX_FILE_SIZE: 750 000` - numbers don't have formatting in any programming language - instead you should write: `MAX_FILE_SIZE: 750000`. I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it will definitely make your program compile and run better.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no files in fileInput, you cannot get files by index value.
Check the files before access.

```
({
MAX_FILE_SIZE: 750 000,
save: function(component) {
    var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
    if(fileInput.files){
       var file = fileInput.files[0];
    }
    var fr = new FileReader();
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Use below one line of code for file upload it is possible to upload upto 2 gb size file

```
<lightning:fileUpload label="Attach File"
                      multiple="false" 
                      recordId="{!v.myRecordId}" 
                      onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" 
                      />
```